# SpriteKit: detect complete node overlap

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, sknode

I have two SKShapeNodes – one with an edge-based SKPhysicsBody, one volume-based – and I want to detect their intersection without collision. I've got this working fine, with the SKPhysicsContactDelegate contact methods getting called as one passes over another, but my issue is that `didEndContact` gets called when the *edges* no longer intersect, even when one body is completely contained within the other. What's the best way to determine true contact or overlap, not just edge intersection? I've tried `usesPreciseCollisionDetection`, to no avail.

Comment: what about adding a child with alpha to 0 and use that one as part of the logic check? you wont see it but it will be colliding all the time...and in your didBeginContact you should try a switch statement, you can tell there which objects are colliding instead of doing a count of all touches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [meisenman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2494064/meisenman) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412487/spritekit-detect-complete-node-overlap/24413018#24413018), it looks like the best way to do this is using the `containsPoint` method to determine true node overlap. The docs state that this "returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a point lies inside the node's bounding box", but in my experimentation it looks like this works for concave edge-based shapes as well.

So if I want to detect when two objects no longer overlap, it makes sense to do a `containsPoint` check within `didEndContact` – but it turns out `didEndContact` gets called when each edge is no longer intersected, even if another edge of the same shape still intersects the same object. For example, a ball exiting a rectangle through its corner will yield *two* `didEndContact` events. Therefore, it's necessary to keep an absolute count of contact events (the difference between begin and end), and only test for containment when this count is zero.

My solution, in Swift:

```
var _contactCount = 0

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!) {
  if ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) == (CATEGORY_ONE | CATEGORY_TWO)) {
    if (_contactCount == 0) {
      // Contact is actually beginning
    }
    _contactCount += 1
  }
}

func didEndContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!) {
  if ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) == (CATEGORY_ONE | CATEGORY_TWO)) {
    _contactCount -= 1
    let overlap = contact.bodyA.node.containsPoint(contact.bodyB.node.position) || contact.bodyB.node.containsPoint(contact.bodyA.node.position)
    if (!overlap && _contactCount == 0) {
      // Contact is actually ending
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice job!  Glad you found the complete answer!

Answer (score 7):

```
CGPoint locObj1 = [sprite1 locationInNode:self];
CGPoint locObj2 = [sprite2 locationInNode:self];

if([sprite1 containsPoint: locObj2]) return;
if([sprite2 containsPoint: locObj1]) return;
```

Add this to the beginning of didBeginContact and didEndContact.  This checks to see if one of the nodes contains the other node.  If it does, it does nothing which will alleviate your issue of didBeginContact and didEndContact being unessesarily called.  I am not on my mac so you may need to play with the syntax a bit.  Hope this sends you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Looks from the docs like `containsPoint` "returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a point lies inside the node's bounding box." I'm concerned that this might not be accurate enough for my use case (i.e. only testing the bounding box for potentially concave edge-based bodies). I can't find a more rigorous alternative to `containsPoint`, though.

Comment: Does one of your nodes have to have an edge based physics body?

Comment: Yep – unfortunately it looks like volume-based bodies need to be defined as convex polygons, while the shapes I'm working with can sometimes be concave.

Comment: Very interesting predicament you are in.  I will continue to search for a solution as I do not believe SpriteKit should/would be limited like this.  I think the spriteKit community should take more of an interest in this post and potentially someone will come through with ... a custom containsPoint that fulfills your convex shape requirement.

Comment: I've been experimenting with this, and I think the documentation is wrong! containsPoint seems to work with convex polygons (at least in my context, and using iOS 8), but there's one more complexity I need to account for. I'll upvote this, then post an even more complete answer for anyone else who runs into this.

Answer (score 0):

These are my thoughts on #meisenman example for swift 3. Instead of collision detection through masks, let's say we wanted to to know if an node is inside a node. With #meisenman, the location of the node is being used for each.

[image: Image Example of CGPoint's of two different nodes.]

This following image is what we actually what I want done.

[image: Image example of two CGPoint's within one another.]

The code #meisenman uses does not require SKPhysics. Here is the code in Swift 3.0

```
let Object_1: CGPoint! = Sprite_Object_1.position
//this obtains the location of the sprite node, through CGPoint.
if Object_Sprite_2.contains(Object_1){
    print("Then it is true, object 2 is within the location of object 1")
}
```

The only limitations that I have found are that if the center of these nodes are not within the body of the desired node, then this if statement will not be true. This has not been tested by setting the node's body defination (mask).

What I like, is having the ability to use this if statement throughout different functions or overide fuctions, this is not limited to only 'did begin' or 'touches moved.'
[image: Image example of two CGPoint's within one another, with possible limitations.]

Comment: Also note - Object 3 shows an example of the limitations of this alternative method.